# Need explanation on structure of Object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I did a console.log of some parameter that is available to a callback function in the Node.js formidable package. I am using this package for processing file uploads. The output of the console.log(files) is:

```
{   
 fileUpload: [
    PersistentFile {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      lastModifiedDate: 2023-02-16T19:45:33.257Z,
      filepath: '/home/uploads/someName',
      newFilename: '8655b57ce96e3b679ffdd7e00',
      originalFilename: 'anotherFile.jpg',
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      hashAlgorithm: false,
      size: 7,
      _writeStream: [WriteStream],
      hash: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }   
   ]   
}
```

I am expecting an object with each key('fileUpload', for example) having as value an array of objects. I am unable to understand the role of **PersistentFile** in the object's structure. I think that it breaks the conventional structure of an object. It gives a syntax error if I try to copy/paste it to a variable.

How can I process this data structure (or object, or whatever...) in Javascript?

**EDIT**:
My need is to get only properties from this object which have scalar values only: lastModifiedDate, filepath, originalFilename, mimetype, and size. So the resultant object will be:

```
{
 fileUpload: [
              {
               originalFilename:
               filepath:...
               ...
              },
              {
               originalFilename:
               filepath:...
               ...
              }
             ],
 fileField2: [
              {...},
              {...}
              ...
             ],
 ...
}
```

Comment: The console is describing the data in a human-readable format, not JavaScript literal syntax. `PersistentFile` is the class or prototype name of the object.

Comment: Presumably the specification of this API you're calling indicates exactly what is returned beyond "array of object".

Comment: @Barmar  Perhaps the better/follow-up question is: How do I convert this to a pure JS object. I cannot JSON.stringify it to convert into a string to be manipulated. This comes from the **formidable** module of Node.js.

Comment: It's probably not something that can be serialized, it's a representation of a file that you can read or write.

Comment: @Sunny The formidable documentation should tell you want you can do with this object. (I assume you're not asking us how to process that `console.log` output?)

Comment: This object contains a `WriteStream` object which is not serializable in JSON because it has a live file handle in it.  You could copy select properties out of this into a new object and then serialize that, but you don't actually explain what the higher-level real problem is here that you're trying to solve so we can't advise on that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have edited the question to answer your question about my need. I ought to have done it when I posted it.

Comment: @jfriend00  I just assigned each key in the object to a temp object and  JSON.stringified it. It only extracted the properties which could be serialized. Mission accomplished. Your comment helped. If you post it as an answer, would certainly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This object contains a `WriteStream` object which is not serializable in JSON because it has a live file handle in it. You could copy select properties out of this into a new object and then serialize that using `JSON.stringify()`.